# RewriteRule to redirect subfolder and parameters to parked domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

This won't work, I don't know why...

```
# let's say I'm in HTACCESS of domain www.aaa.com
RewriteRule subfolder/script\.php\?param=value&param2=value2 http://www.bbb.ccom/otherscript.php?otherparam=othervalue [QSA,L]

# domain bbb.com is mine, BUT not on the same account (but same server)
```

It's not causing any bug or loop, it simply plain not work.

Other instructions in the HTACCESS does work (rewriterules among them) so I know the RewriteEngine is on and works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It simply won't work because RewriteRule doesn't match QUERY_STRING. You will RewriteCond for that. Use code like below:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} param=value&param2=value2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^subfolder/script\.php$ http://www.bbb.ccom/otherscript.php?otherparam=othervalue [QSA,L,R]
```

Comment: This works 90% as I want to, thanks!  Only problem is that I don't want QSA to be appended "as is", I want to either completely remove it, or assing NEW parameters...  Removing the QSA flag won't work (just tried)

Comment: OK, worked, I removed the automatically appended QSA (even without the flag) by simply putting a question mark à the end of the RewriteRule. http://www.bbb.ccom/?

Comment: Yes that's right putting `?` in the end strips existing query string.